# Definition of “function” in the category $ \textbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory

While studying natural transformations, I realize that perhaps I have not been thinking of the category $ \textbf{Set}$ correctly.  I am also questioning what we mean by the morphisms in $ \textbf{Set}$  being “functions from one set to another.”

Take two objects in the category $ \textbf{Set}$ : S = {s1, s2, s3} and T = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5} and the morphisms (functions) from S to T.  We would normally think of “functions from S to T” as maps from single elements in S to single elements in T, such as f(s1)=t2, or f(s3)=t3, etc.  As we learned in middle school, or earlier, these are functions from S to T precisely because they map each and every single element of S to exactly one element of T.

However, in some cases which I’ve encountered, the morphisms/functions in $ \textbf{Set}$ imply that a valid function in this category is from the whole set S to whole set T, i.e. a function of the form f(S)=T.  (Specifically, this seems to be the case in the functor category [G, $ \textbf{Set}$] where the morphisms in this category are maps in $ \textbf{Set}$ from whole sets to whole sets, not elements of sets to elements of sets.  For example, see Leinster’s text p. 29.)

This opens up the question of what is a valid “function” from one set to another.  If a whole set can map to a whole set, can the argument of the function be any subset of the domain set, and can the image of the function be a subset of the target set?

If this is the case, then a function could map a single element of S to two elements in T (since two elements in T are just a subset of T).  This is hardly what is normally meant by “a function from S to T.”

To restate my question with specific examples, which of the following four maps f are valid functions/morphisms between S and T in $ \textbf{Set}$ ?

f(S) = t1   ;    f maps the whole set S to the element t1.

f(s1) = T   ;   f maps a single element in S to the whole set T

f({s1,s2}) = {t1,t3,t5}   ;  f maps a subset of S to subset of T

f(S) = T     ;   f maps the whole set S to the whole set T
(this is just a special case of the last example)

I don’t see anything in the definition of $ \textbf{Set}$ that bars these functions, but this is hardly conforms to the normal idea of functions between sets.  If these are valid morphisms, then “functions between sets” has two or more meanings.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Functions in the category of sets, as well as the category of $G$-sets, are as you learned in middle school: they take elements of sets to elements of sets. Given a function $X\overset{f}\to Y$ you can always induce functions on subsets of the domain and/or codomain. But these are not the morphisms in your mentioned categories.

Comment: It seems your real issue is with understanding the definition of $[G,\mathbf{Set}]$.  I would suggest you explain what you think the definition is.

Answer (score 2):

Functions in the category of sets, as well as the category of $G$-sets, are as you learned in middle school: they take elements of sets to elements of sets. Given a function $S\overset{f}\to T$ you can always induce functions on subsets of the domain and/or codomain. But these are not the morphisms in your mentioned categories.

> To restate my question with specific examples, which of the following four maps f are valid functions/morphisms between S and T in Set
>   Set
>    ?
>
> f(S) = t1 ; f maps the whole set S to the element t1.

Given a $t_1\in T$, there constant map with $f(s)=t_1$ for all $s\in S.$ It may be better to denote it $f(S)=\{t_1\}$ than the way you did, but I may be splitting hairs.

> f(s1) = T ; f maps a single element in S to the whole set T

Not a valid function in the category of sets between $S$ and $T$.

> f({s1,s2}) = {t1,t3,t5} ; f maps a subset of S to subset of T

Not valid.

> f(S) = T ; f maps the whole set S to the whole set T (this is just a special case of the last example)

Not a valid map $S\to T$.

But note that there are two common powerset functors from the category sets to itself. A contravariant functor that takes a map $S\overset{f}\to T$ to the preimage map $\wp(T)\overset{f^{-1}}\to\wp(S).$ And a covariant functor which takes maps $S\overset{f}\to T$ to the image function on subsets $\wp(S)\overset{f}\to\wp(T).$ So the examples you listed are not valid functions of elements of sets, but they *are* valid functions on sets of sets. They are functions between the powersets of $S$ and $T$.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer supplements ziggurism's answer.]

I think you have misinterpreted Leinster's G-set example (Example 1.3.4 p.29); this is the source of your confusion. Let's walk through it.

The "middle school" definition of a G-set for a group $G$ is a set $\hat{S}$ with an operation $(g,s)\mapsto g\cdot s$, $G\times\hat{S}\rightarrow\hat{S}$. Now think of $G$ as a category with one object (call it *), whose morphisms are the "elements" of $G$; the group operation $(g_1,g_2)\mapsto g_1 g_2$ is just the composition operation of the category.

OK, let's look at a functor $S$ from $G$ to **Set**. So we must have a set $S(*)$, recalling that * is the unique object of $G$. Let $\hat{S}=S(*)$. For every morphism $g$ in $G$, we have a morphism $S(g)$ in **Set** from $S(*)$ to $S(*)$, i.e., a plain old "middle school" function from $\hat{S}$ to $\hat{S}$. Now, for any element $s\in\hat{S}$ and morphism (group element) $g$ in $G$, let's write
$$
S(g)(s)=g\cdot s
$$
this defines the G-set action of $G$ on $\hat{S}$. Note that $S(g)$ takes elements to elements, not whole sets to whole sets.

Finally, if you have two G-sets $S$ and $T$, i.e., two functors from $G$ to **Set**, you can ask what a natural transformation from $S$ to $T$ looks like. For every object $A$ in $G$ we need a morphism $\alpha_A$ in **Set**, the component of the natural transformation. But there is only one object in $G$! So we have a single morphism (i.e., function) $\alpha$ in **Set**. The naturality square gives equivariance equation, as Leinster states.

Comment: Here is the paragraph from Leinster:  ”Such a natural transformation consists of a single map in Set (since G has just one object), satisfying some axioms. Precisely, it is a function α: S → T such that α(g · s) = g · α(s) for all s ∈ S and g ∈ G. “. He certainly seems to be saying the map from S to T is a function in the category Set.

Comment: That's right, $\alpha$ is a function in the category Set, which is a function in the "middle school" sense. Note that in the equation, $\alpha$ is applied to *elements* of $S$. He doesn't write $\alpha(S)$ or anything like that.

Comment: Technically, when Leinster says that the natural transformation "is a function $\alpha:S\rightarrow T$", he should really say, "the natural transformation corresponds canonically to a function $\alpha:S\rightarrow T$" etc. Also, he is using the letters $S$ and $T$ with two slightly different meanings: as functors from the group (regarded as a category) to Set, and as the images $S(*)$ and $T(*)$. This sort of "abuse of notation" is pretty common. In my answer, I distinguished the two uses, writing $\hat{S}$ and $\hat{T}$ for the images (which are objects in Set, i.e., sets).

Comment: Finally, there's a tendency in category theory (and elsewhere!) to say two things are the same, when you really mean they correspond in a canonical manner. For example, when we say the group $G$ **is** a category with one object. The "middle school" group isn't a category, it's a set with a binary operation. The set of morphisms of the "group-as-category" in fact **is** a middle school group, and we can go from the middle school group to the group-as-category just by adding in a unique object * and declaring the elements of the group to be morphisms from * to *.